# Why are shared libraries linked with absolute paths on OS X?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking, dyld

So I'm porting a game from Linux to OS X and having successfully compiled and linked it, I'm now running up against problems starting it – the dynamic linker can't find the libs.

Here's the `otool -L` output:

```
./foo:
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
        @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 3.1.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libGLEW.1.10.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.10.0, current version 1.10.0)
        /usr/lib/libtheoradec.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.4.0)
        /usr/lib/libtheora.0.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.10.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libvorbis.0.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.7.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.2.0)
        @loader_path/libsteam_api.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /Users/macosx/some/path/to/code/openal-soft-1.16.0/build/libopenal.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.16.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
```

The thing is, some of those paths are plain wrong. For instance, neither GLEW nor Ogg/Vorbis/Theora exist in `/usr/…`, and for whatever reason the path to OpenAL Soft is burnt in as an absolute one to where it was built.

Still, by setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly, I can get the game to start. However, for multiple reasons I'd prefer not to embed my system's absolute paths within the binary.

What's going on here? Is there a way to force relative paths (that's the `@loader_path` thing, I presume?) on libraries of my choice? Is there documentation on the matter available?

Comment: Yeah it's complicated but during linking the absolute paths are embedded within the executable.  Dylibs which are not part of the system have to be moved into the `Frameworks` folder of the app bundle and `install_name` used to change their path in the executable.  There are various articles on how to do this on the net.

Comment: OK, so if I search for "install names" I should be able to locate the relevant documentation, right?

Comment: I don't think so, no.  The tool is called `install_name`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! `install_name_tool -change <from> <to> <executable>` does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Just as @trojanfoe suggested – this works:

`install_name_tool -change <from> <to> <executable>`