Why do my linked dylibs not read from the lib folder using cpack in the built program?
Attached below is my cmakelists.txt, I don't know why, but when I use cpack to create the bundled folder, it is reading the dylibs from the original location. I know this because I delete the dylibs and it still links, as well, deleting the dylibs from where they originally were breaks it. Weirdly enough, LuaCpp is linked just fine, but the other 3 are incorrect. I really hope someone knows why they aren't linked properly. This script runs just fine and compiles, but it doesn't read the dylibs from the right spot. If someone could review my cmakelists I would appreciate it a lot.
When deleting the LuaCpp dylib inside the lib folder and running the packed program:
dyld[51173]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libluacpp.dylib
  Referenced from: <DFF279D6-542E-30DB-AF11-8A48C9619EA8> /Users/me/RainSDL/packages/Game-0.1-Darwin/bin/Game
  Reason:
    tried: '/Users/me/RainSDL/packages/Game-0.1-Darwin/bin/lib/libluacpp.dylib

When deleting the dylib from the brew directory for SDL_image (which should not be linked from there, but from the lib folder):
dyld[51216]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: <DFF279D6-542E-30DB-AF11-8A48C9619EA8> /Users/me/RainSDL/packages/Game-0.1-Darwin/bin/Game
  Reason:
    tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file),
  '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib',
 '/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file) 

This is not what I want SDL_image to do. I want it to be linked from the lib folder. As well, deleting the SDL_image.dylib file from inside the lib folder has no error.
The dylibs are stored in bin/lib in the final packed program. The dylibs are stored on my system originally using brew in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/.
OS: Sonoma 14.3, Macbook Pro M2, homebrew
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# Project name and version
project(Game VERSION 0.1)

# Set compiler paths and build type
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Build") # Change to "Build" for proper lua script linking

# Set optimization level
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")

# Set C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Find Lua
find_package(Lua REQUIRED)

# Find LuaCpp
find_library(LUACPP_LIBRARIES NAMES LuaCpp PATHS /usr/local/lib)

# Find SDL2
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

# Find SDL2 image
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

# Include directories
include_directories(
    ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    "/usr/local/include/LuaCpp" # LuaCpp headers
    "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_image/2.8.2_1/include/SDL2" # SDL2 image headers
)

# Add your source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

# Create the executable
add_executable(Game ${SOURCES})

# Link against libraries
target_link_libraries(Game 
    ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} 
    ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY} 
    ${LUA_LIBRARIES} 
    ${LUACPP_LIBRARIES} # Linked library
)

# Set LC_RPATH
if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(Game PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/../bin/lib")
endif()

# Copy necessary dynamic libraries to the lib directory
add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different 
        ${LUACPP_LIBRARIES} 
        ${LUA_LIBRARIES} 
        ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY} 
        $<TARGET_FILE:SDL2::SDL2> 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib
)

# Use CPack to create a distributable package
install(TARGETS Game
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

# Install libraries
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    DESTINATION bin
)

# Install Lua scripts directory
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lua
    DESTINATION bin/src
)

# Determine the relative path from the executable to the Lua scripts directory
file(RELATIVE_PATH LUA_SCRIPTS_RELATIVE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lua)

# Define a compile definition for the Lua scripts path
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    target_compile_definitions(Game PRIVATE LUA_SCRIPTS_PATH="src/lua")
else()
    target_compile_definitions(Game PRIVATE LUA_SCRIPTS_PATH="${LUA_SCRIPTS_RELATIVE}")
endif()

# CPack configuration
set(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages")
include(CPack)

I have tried linking them like the LuaCpp, and that has not worked. I tried everything I could think of, but I could not find a solution.
EDIT:
After a few hours of trying, I still can't quite figure it out. I added this code block under the first apple block where it sets the LC_RPATH
if(APPLE)
    # List of shared libraries to modify
    set(SHARED_LIBRARIES
        ${LUACPP_LIBRARIES}
        ${LUA_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY}
        ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} 
    )

    # Loop over each shared library
    foreach(LIBRARY ${SHARED_LIBRARIES})    
        # Get the filename of the shared library
        get_filename_component(LIBRARY_NAME "${LIBRARY}" NAME)
        add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
            COMMAND install_name_tool -change "${LIBRARY}" "@rpath/${LIBRARY_NAME}" "$<TARGET_FILE:Game>"
        )
    endforeach()
    # print the new path
    add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
        COMMAND otool -L "$<TARGET_FILE:Game>"
    )
endif()

This doesn't actually change the @rpaths in the linked libraries. Swapping the arguments in the install_name_tool command makes the one properly linked library no longer properly linked, instead reading from the original directory.
I think the snippet is looping over the libraries and changing the read location of the dylibs to the relative paths using @rpath. Clearly though, it is not doing this. I tried moving it around, above and below the other code chunks, I tried using -id, but it just broke my brew libraries so I had to reinstall them.
EDIT:
I just manually hardcoded the paths and it works fine, I ended up realizing all my Library paths were messed up, so the command would fail.
if(APPLE)
    # I have to hardcode these because otherwise the paths are wrong
    add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
        COMMAND install_name_tool -change "/opt/homebrew/opt/lua/lib/liblua.dylib" "@rpath/liblua5.4.dylib" "$<TARGET_FILE:Game>"
    )
    add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
        COMMAND install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/include/LuaCpp" "@rpath/libluacpp.dylib" "$<TARGET_FILE:Game>"
    )
    add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
        COMMAND install_name_tool -change "/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib" "@rpath/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib" "$<TARGET_FILE:Game>"
    )
    add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
        COMMAND install_name_tool -change "/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib" "@rpath/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib" "$<TARGET_FILE:Game>"
    )
        # print the new path
    add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD
        COMMAND otool -L "$<TARGET_FILE:Game>"
    )
endif()

So it's functional and that's just how I like my code.

"... it is reading the dylibs from the original location. I know this because I delete the dylibs and it still links, as well, deleting the dylibs from where they originally were breaks it." - This is very vague description of the problem. Please, show (add to the question post) the exact error message you got when run your program from the bundle.

It's not an error message, it's just that it is reading the dylibs from the original location they were when I linked them (ie. homebrew) I want it have them read from the lib directory. None of them are read from the lib directory except for LuaCpp. I know this because deleting the dylibs in the lib directory doesn't break the program and deleting them from the brew dir does break it.

When deleting the LuaCpp dylib
dyld[51173]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libluacpp.dylib
Referenced from:  /Users/me/RainSDL/packages/Game-0.1-Darwin/bin/Game
Reason: tried: '/Users/me/RainSDL/packages/Game-0.1-Darwin/bin/lib/libluacpp.dylib' (no such file)
Deleting the SDL2_image dylib doesn't have any error at all, except when I remove the brew directory, it appears to not actually be the dylib but pointing to it. It's too long to put here so it'll be in another comment.

dyld[51216]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib
Referenced from:  /Users/me/RainSDL/packages/Game-0.1-Darwin/bin/Game
Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib', '/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file)
@Tsyvarev

Note on the path in the Library not loaded: line: That path is contained in library as "install name" property, copied from the library to the executable by the linker, and searched by the runtime loader when you run the executable. That is, the library libluacpp.dylib has install name @rpath/libluacpp.dylib, which is embedded into Game executable when you link it and searched by runtime loader. The runtime loader substitutes instead of @rpath a path from RPATH settings of your executable. So that library could be located in the bundle.

The library libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib has install name /opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib, so this path is embedded into the Game executable and runtime loader searches the library by that path. Note, that given path doesn't contain @rpath part, so your RPATH settings doesn't affect on the search. That library could be found only at its original path /opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib.

In the executable, if you want to change the reference to the library from absolute path to @rpath-based variant, then you could use install_name_tool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884822/why-are-shared-libraries-linked-with-absolute-paths-on-os-x
